# What are the requirements of a NETSuite PDF Template that will allow it to accept a page break?

Tags: netsuite

Currently trying to write my first NETSuite PDF template, and am struggling with so many aspects of it.

I am unable to add an "End Of Page" to my template.

[image]

When I click the button, nothing happens.

I have tried...

1. Examining default templates in which I can add pages, and identifying the code change associated with the change. I could not find any change.
2. Creating a brand new template, and trying to add a new page. I was not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"End of Page" just inserts a page break - `<pbr />`.

You can switch to Source Code view to see exactly where it's inserted, and usually it's not where you want if you're using the WYSIWYG editor.  So you can move or manually enter the `<pbr />` in the correct place in the Source Code editor instead.